# adding content to a generated tab in JQuery

Tags: jquery, tabs

I added this to my already existing JQuery tab:

```
function createTab(name) {
    // this will add a tab via the standard method
    $("#tabs").tabs("add", "#fragment-4", name);
    $("#fragment-" + name).css("display", "block");
}
```

my question is, what is the syntax that allows me to create content inside the newly created tab?

Comment: please format so it's legible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the contents to the div you are adding:

```
$('#fragment4').html('Contents added via JS');
```

Comment: except, replace <b> tags with <strong> tags! :D

Comment: Tags inside html() are not relevant for the answer. I removed them all.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the template plugin.

```
<script id="SomeTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <h3>A Header with ${some_variable} in it</h3>
        Your content
</script>
```

Then inside the .add event in tabs, you can append it to the current tab

```
$tabs = $("#tabs").tabs({
            add: function( event, ui ) {
                var data_to_pass = {some_variable:"data"};
                $("#SomeTemplate").tmpl(data_to_pass).appendTo(ui.panel);
            }
        });
```